# How to join URLs in Go?

Tags: go, web-scraping, web-crawler

I'm creating a web crawler in GO. And after parsing and **scraping** all the URLs on the page, there are scenarios where I'm getting the hyperlinks in different formats:

- /my/next/page
- my/next/page
- //my_next_page
- https://different-domain.com

As you can see, there are many combinations here, and in some cases, the URL is entirely a different domain. The regular joins of the URLs will not work here. How to join URLs correctly so each resultant URL join can be fed into the crawler again to parse and scrape continuously?

Answer (score 1):

URLs handling is different because of differences in the hyperlinks. As mentioned above, the hyperlink in an anchor tag can be in many formats. Here is the solution to handle the joins of a requested URL to the crawl and hyperlinks respectively to that URL.

```golang
func joinURLs(baseURL, hyperlink string) string {
    parse, err := url.Parse(hyperlink)
    if err != nil {
        return ""
    }
    base, err := url.Parse(baseURL)
    if err != nil {
        return ""
    }
    nextURLToCrawl := base.ResolveReference(parse)
    return nextURLToCrawl.String()
}
```

The best thing about this function is that it can handle functions that are on a different domain without having to maintain the checks whether the hostname is the same or not. Now your code is much more declarative.

Comment: Remember that when dealing with HTML, the `baseURL` passed to this function should be the content of the `href` attribute of the `base` tag in `head` if there is one, or the URL of the page the link is on if there is no `base`.